# SQL Triggers Need to delete records from log tabel

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to keep only 3 recent updated records from the log table of same ID. Can any one tell mw how can i achieve this using Triggers and sql server please...[Tabel called log]

Comment: Why do this in a trigger, which forces the user inserting the new row(s) to wait for you to delete older rows? Create a view that just gets the most recent three per ID (search for "top N per group"), have the users _reading_ the log use the view instead, and have a background process that deletes the older ones from the table _without_ being part of the regular activity transactions. The nice thing about this is you can control how aggressive you want to be about deletes without worrying about how accurate the _exposed_ data is, because the users will only ever see the last 3.

Comment: Sure i'll try this

Comment: So I would re-word the question - you want users to only see the last three rows, don't pre-decide that the way you want to solve the problem is with a trigger.

Comment: Exactly sir, this what am looking for

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d38ae1025a42b5a51369b399f7b20b12